# Android SimpleDateFormat not handling 'X' when its supposed to

Tags: android

**Please read carefuly before slapping that duplicate button**

according to android docs, [SimpleDateFormat](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) is supposed to be able to handle the 'X' chracter which is for ISO 8601 standard. and it says this was added in API1.

**I dont want 'Z', I want 'X'**

Z is for RFC 822, I want ISO 8601

but running this even on android sdk 26 I get an error saying X is an ilegal character. Works fine on Oreo

`new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX");`

`IllegalArgumentException: Unknown pattern character 'X'`

update:

the time stamp I want to parse looks like this:
`2017-08-22T20:37:24.000Z`

the Z at the end doesn't mean I need to put Z in my format, it stands for 'zero' in the  ISO 8601 standard

Comment: Please show date as it's received.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's a documentation bug.